# How to set spark standalone master url in play-framework conf/application.conf file?

Tags: apache-spark, production-environment, playframework-2.5, apache-spark-standalone

plugging the play application with spark standalone cluster it executes well on    dev mode but when trying to deploy in production mode it gives following error:

```
 Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
```

I am using spark-2.1 here is the snippet

```
lazy val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark_with_Play").master("spark://ip:7077").config("spark.executor.memory", "2g").config("spark.deploy.defaultCores",8).getOrCreate()
```

So how can i  set spark master in conf/appliaction.conf file in **production mode** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials able to find **typesafe config**  which is used to read the configurations from application.conf file and pass those into code.
here is the content of **application.conf** file:

```
spark.master = "spark://ip:7077"
```

here is the line which is added to **build.sbt**

```
"com.typesafe"%"config"%"1.2.0"
```

in controller  here is code the snippet:

```
import com.typesafe.config._
val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
val sparkMaster = conf.getString("spark.master")

val spark= SparkSession.builder().master(sparkMaster).getOrCreate()
```